# Shopify Cart API bundled section rendering in Dawn

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api

I am attempting to build a mini cart using Shopify's base Dawn template.

In assets/cart.js the getSectionsToRender function supplies a section id from a data-id attribute. This is then used by a fetch to the Cart Api which has [bundled section rendering](https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart#bundled-section-rendering).

```js
  getSectionsToRender() {
    return [
      {
        id: 'main-cart-items',
        section: document.getElementById('main-cart-items').dataset.id || 'main-cart-items',
        selector: '.js-contents',
      },
      {
        id: 'cart-icon-bubble',
        section: 'cart-icon-bubble',
        selector: '.shopify-section'
      },
      {
        id: 'cart-live-region-text',
        section: 'cart-live-region-text',
        selector: '.shopify-section'
      },
      {
        id: 'main-cart-footer',
        section: document.getElementById('main-cart-footer').dataset.id || 'main-cart-footer',
        selector: '#main-cart-footer',
      }
    ];
  }

  updateQuantity(line, quantity, name) {
    this.enableLoading(line);

    const body = JSON.stringify({
      line,
      quantity,
      sections: this.getSectionsToRender().map((section) => section.section),
      sections_url: window.location.pathname
    });

    fetch(`${routes.cart_change_url}`, {...fetchConfig(), ...{ body }})
      .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((state) => {
        const parsedState = JSON.parse(state);
        console.log(parsedState.sections);
      });
  }
```

When the dynamic section id is used eg `template--15179940757682__cart-footer` the cart api returns the full main-cart-footer element. However the dynamic section id is not available on other pages and in this context I am using `main-cart-footer` as the section id. Without the dynamic id the cart api returns main-cart-footer with some of the content missing. I have used the same approach with main-cart-items and there are no issues.

I have tried using sections_url parameter set to `/cart` to specify the page context but this is not working either.

Anyone have any idea how to get the main-cart-footer without a dynamic section id?

Comment: For any one else having this issue it was solved by adding default settings to `main-cart-footer.liquid`


  "default": {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "subtotal"
      },
      {
        "type": "buttons"
      }
    ]
  }

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a static section just like "cart-live-region-text"? If you create a section like this and add your code in the section(in your case cart footer where cart subtotal gets updated) then you don't need a dynamic section id, you can write the section name(the section which you create) directly in the section id.
You can checkout the following link
https://shopify.dev/api/section-rendering#find-section-ids

Comment: Thanks for that idea @ChiragDarji I'lll give that a go next time